Android - ADB command to perform "drag" gesture?
I would like to simulate a complicated gesture, such as pressing down a finger, drawing a shape and then lifting the finger up.
I found how to do it with sendevent, but my OS reports permission denied back when I try to sendevent, so I would like to do it using adb shell input.
I am steering the device, an andorid samsungs through an ubuntu.
I am explcitely not looking for the "shape" line, i.e. the swipe command. I am looking for something that can draw curves or spirals uninterrupted, i.e. not in small increments of the swipe action.

It's perfectly possible to do it with swipe. Here is an example using AndroidViewClient/culebra.
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

def toint(n):
    return n.item()

def npint(a):
    return np.round(a).astype(int)

def spiral(t):
    a = 0.5  # Controls the tightness of the spiral
    b = 0.5  # Controls the spacing between turns
    g = 40 # Factor
    dx = 400 # Delta x
    dy = 600 # Delta y
    x = g * a * t * np.cos(t + b) + dx
    y = g * a * t * np.sin(t + b) + dy
    return list(zip(map(toint, npint(x)), map(toint, npint(y))))

# get helper
helper = ViewClient.view_client_helper()

# generate values for the parameter t
t = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)

# calculate (x, y) coordinates
segments = spiral(t)

# assume google keep is open so we can see it drawing
# see spiral.gif
helper.ui_device.swipe(segments=segments, segment_steps=5)

and this is the result (using Google Keep to draw)

See animation.
